# Cheque Number problem

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column called check_num (bank check number) as VARCHAR2 type in a payment_line table(Oracle).

The  requirement is "I have to search all those checks which numbers are greater than 12345.

Please suggest how can I achieve this?

Comment: Note: if you are doing this often, you might consider storing the data in the most appropriate (ordinal) form... i.e. a numeric type in this case.

Comment: Well the table has been designed and created by database team, I can't change the data type to Number. I already communicated this issue with them. If we change the data type of that column, it could impact the application. So basically I want a solution without any changes in the table structure.

Comment: what should you do with check_num vals that contain non-numeric chars?

Comment: Yes it could have non-numeric too.

Comment: If it would be Numeric field I would not be asking this question in the forum, it would be a simple query to get the greater numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There most likely is a more elegant solution, but this should do the trick:

```
SELECT * 
FROM payment_line pl 
WHERE LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(pl.check_num, '0123456789',' '))) IS NULL 
   AND TRIM(TRANSLATE(pl.check_num, '0123456789','0123456789')) > 12345;
```

**edit:**

If I understand your comment to Adam Paynter, for input of:

```
0A132 
1A117 
2A123 
12D24 
02134 
11111 
12345 
21334
```

and you used `1A117` as your comparison the resulting set would be:

```
2A123 
12D24 
02134 
11111 
12345 
21334
```

Can you confirm that both `02134` and `11111` should be in this result set?  They dont seem to meet the requirements of `>` a value like `1A117`.  If, however, that was a typo, you can actually run a simple string comparison to get this set:

```
SELECT * 
FROM payment_line pl
WHERE pl.check_num > '1A117';
```

**edit 2**

OK, I think I see where you are going with this.  You are looking to get the rows in the db that have been entered after the input row.  If you look at my formatted list above, you will see that your result set is everything below your input string.  So, with that in mind, i submit for your approval the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM payment_line  
WHERE rowid > (select rowid from payment_line where check_num ='1A117');
```

Comment: TRIM(TRANSLATE(pl.check_num, '0123456789','0123456789')) > 12345

How about where check_num = '6'?

Comment: Can you confirm that both 02134 and 11111 should be in this result set? 
Ans is YES.

Comment: and by the way pl.check_num > '1A117'; clause doesn't work properly for VARCHAR.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Oracle does not provide a handy function such as `IS_INTEGER(...)`, otherwise you could have done a query like:

```
-- Fictional, though desirable, query:
SELECT *
FROM  checks
WHERE IS_INTEGER(check_num) AND TO_NUMBER(check_num) > 12345
```

However, there is a way to emulate such a function:

```
-- Real, though less-than-desirable, query:
SELECT *
FROM  checks
WHERE TRIM(TRANSLATE(check_num, '0123456789', '          ')) IS NULL
  AND TO_NUMBER(check_num) > 12345
```

The `TRANSLATE(check_num, '0123456789', '          ')` call replaces each digit within `check_num` with a space. For example:

```
 check_num          TRANSLATE(check_num, '0123456789', '          ')
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 '12345'            '     '
 'cat'              'cat'
 '123cat45'         '   cat  '
```

Therefore, if `check_num` contains **only** digits, then `TRIM(TRANSLATE(check_num, '0123456789', '          '))` will be `NULL` (that is, the empty string).

Comment: Can you write a query for this scenario:
0A132
1A117
2A123
12D24
02134
11111
12345
21334

If I pass '1A117', the query result should be as:
2A123
12D24
02134
11111
12345
21334

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following might help you -

```
select * from checkTable where TO_NUMBER(check_num) > 12345;
```

cheers

Comment: I did this but I was getting 'ORA-01722: invalid number' error and the 2nd thing is that if the check_num will be 123FD5 then how it will function?

Comment: Please consider CHECK_NUM as alphanumeric.

Comment: If that's the case then you have an unclear requirement, what does it mean to "have to search all those checks which numbers are greater than 12345" when the check number can be "123FD"?  Is that hex?  Should you only care about the first number part? Would stripping out all letters be appropriate?  More info

Comment: Also, ORA-01722 means you tried to convert a non number containing string to a number.  So that's how it will function.

Comment: Well, the CHECK_NUM could be anything but the query should return the greater values always.
for example: 
12
013
query should return 12, 013 not 013, 12

Comment: I missed comma in example
its 12, 013

Comment: If results "12, 013" and "013, 12" are meant to be two records then they are equivalent. What are you trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky to use to_number() in this requirement because forcing Oracle to apply a check that the value is safe to convert to a number before it applies the TO_NUMBER function is not so easy, and an ORA-01722 error might surface in the future.

I think that I would:

```
SELECT * 
FROM payment_line pl 
WHERE LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(pl.check_num, '0123456789',' '))) IS NULL 
   AND LPAD(pl.check_num,10,'0') > TO_CHAR(12345,'fm0000000000');
```

You might ask for the creation of an index on LPAD(pl.check_num,10,'0') to help with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on 10g or later you can use regular expressions with an inline view.

The inner select is to get only the numeric check numbers. Then converting and using the where clause is easy. Something like

select * from (
select *
from payment_line
where regexp_like (check_num,'^[0-9]*$')
)
where to_number (check_num) > 12345;

Of course, this only works if you want all numeric check numbers greater than 12345. If you want "numbers" like 1A123 included as well, that's a different story.